# Antlr Error when adding a Mode for Lexers

Tags: parsing, antlr, grammar, antlr4, lexer

I'm trying Lexing Modes for the first time.
I have a lexer grammar with a mode that I'm importing into my "main" grammar.
I get this error when generating the java classes for the Grammar's lexer

'rule DESCRIPTION_FIELD contains a lexer command with an unrecognized constant value; lexer interpreters may produce incorrect output'

I followed this [article](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/lexer-rules.md)
My Lexer grammar is the following :

```
lexer grammar TestLexerGrammar;

DESCRIPTION_FIELD
:
    'DESCRIPTION:'-> pushMode(FREETEXTMODE)
;


mode FREETEXTMODE;

FREE_TEXT_FIELD_FORMAT
:
    STR+
;

fragment
STR
:
    (
        LETTER
        | DIGIT
    )
;
```

my main grammar:

```
grammar Grammar;
import TestLexerGrammar;


descriptionElement
:
    DESCRIPTION_FIELD freeTextFields
;

freeTextFields
:
    FREE_TEXT_FIELD_FORMAT+
;
```

so in the generated GrammarLexer.java I get an error : " FREETEXTMODE cannot be resolved to a variable "

Is this a wrong approach? and is there a possible way to trigger changing mode through a parsing rule?

Comment: The grammar you have proposed (after adding Letter, Digit rules) is fine. It worked for me...

Comment: you are right, sorry I forgot to specify that I'm importing the lexer grammar into a parsing grammar and using the Token DESCRIPTION_FIELD into a rule
(Editing the post)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not use mode in grammars with import statement. There are related issues on github: [Problems with lexical modes inside an imported grammar](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/issues/256) and [No error/incorrect code generation when importing lexer grammar with modes into a combined grammar](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/issues/970).

So, you should repair your main grammar and remove import statement by the following way:

```
parser grammar Grammar;
options { tokenVocab=TestLexerGrammar; }
```